# Creating form in c# with ubuntu linux with mono

Tags: c#, ubuntu

Im on `ubuntu v18 and mono version 6.12` So I have mono installed what I use to compile mine program and to run the program.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

//mcs Program.cs -pkg:dotnet to compile
//mono the exe file to run mono Program.exe

class Program : Form
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args){
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;

        Application.Run(new Program());
    }

    public Program(){
        Text = "Hello world";
    }
}
```

so this is mine code so far what creates a windows form with just `Hello World` but how can I add for example buttons or input fields to this code cause in mine folder I only have 2 files and `Program.cs` and `Program.exe` file or is it possible to link to another form? or can you build it in xml. Im new to csharp and visual.

Comment: Do you hack into vim (some TextEditor) and use cli commands? You should consider using some IDE that has Designer support. [This](https://www.mono-project.com/archived/winforms_designer/) seems outdated, but maybe legit.

Comment: You *could* create your entire application in code (without using a designer, though I wouldn't recommend doing that), just look up a Windows Forms tutorial online